# Why renew section make \ref comand to section labels do not work?

Tags: cross-referencing

An example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\medskip \addtocounter{section}{1}\raggedright \textbf{\Roman{section}. \ #1}\medskip}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}

In \ref{secsec} happens nothing.

\section{Second Section}
\label{secsec}
\end{document}
```

Instead of reading "In 1.1 happens nothing." it reads "In happens nothing." Why?

Comment: you have redefined `\section` to remove almost all its functionality, it is not setting the current label, it is not handling indentation of following text or suppressing page breaks or writing to the table of contents or the page header or pdf bookmarks

Comment: If you want to change the spacing, have a look at package `titlesec` for a user friendly interface or take a look at the indernals of `article.cls` (advanced).

Comment: Thanks David, how could I add the functionality that set the current label?

Comment: you could use `\refstepcounter` instead of adding one by hand with `\addtocounter`, but really _don't_ do this, latex has a whole mechanism for defining section headings and this just destroys it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, section titles need much more than setting a font and spacing. You want to set the label, to avoid a title sits lonely at the bottom of a page and more.

With `titlesec` it's really easy.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\raggedright\bfseries} % the font for the section title
  {\thesection. \ } % what to add for \section (not for \section*)
  {0pt} % the added space between the number and the title
  {} % the title
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt} % no space at the left
  {\medskipamount} % before
  {\medskipamount} % after

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

In \ref{secsec} nothing happens.

\section{Second Section}\label{secsec}

Here as well.

\end{document}
```

[image]